# placing single quote around each words

Tags: php

I have list of words separated by a newline, for example:

```
apple
ball
cat
dog
```

I wanted to separate each of the words by a comma and then place single quotes around each word.

I could remove the newline character and place a comma, but I couldn't enclose each word with single quotes.

I want the final result to look like this:

'apple','ball','cat','dog' and so on.

Here is my code:

```
$words = getlist();

$str = preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim($words));
echo $str;

function getlist($list)
{
    //words list
}
```

Comment: `$str = preg_replace('#\s+#',"','",trim($words));
    echo "'" . $str . '"';`

Comment: Do you really need to use the actual bad words here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do,

```
$strings = explode(",",$str);
$str = "'".implode("','",$strings)."'";
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/fork/qaTuFV)**.

Answer (score 1):

Add double quotes(`""`) around the comma(`,`), like this `"','"`

Try this,

```
$words = 'asdf asdf aewrw werer ewrew';
$str = preg_replace('#\s+#',"','",trim($words));
echo "'" . $str . '"';
```

**[Check out here](http://ideone.com/T5hKEa)**

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
$strong = explode("\n", $string);
$string = "'".implode("','",$strong)."'";
echo $string;
```

Sample Output:

```
'apple','ball','cat','dog'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple:

```
$wordsArray = explode("\n", $words);
$result = "";
foreach ($wordsArray as $word) $result .= "'$word',";
```

You can see the demo here:

http://ideone.com/SLzySu

Answer (score 0):

The sed utility can help you.

```
system('sed "s|\s|\',\'|g" '.$tmpOutputFile .' >> '.$tmpOutputFile1);
system('sed "s|^|\'|g" '.$tmpOutputFile1 .' >> '.$tmpOutputFile2);
system('sed "s|$|\'|g" '.$tmpOutputFile2 .' >> '.$OutputFile);
```